# What will be a good expression/idiom/noun form for "external problems"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

Question from a economics researcher: What will be a good idiom/noun form for "external problems"?

The idea is, to charge for some services, there is no problem inside the company, as all the managers agree that they should be charged. But, (predictably) the customers do not want to pay, as they got used to getting the services for free.

We want to give a label to this situation where the problem lays outside of the company. Your suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: [What is a good idiom for/the problem lies outside the company]

Comment: [**contingency**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/contingency) (noun, formal) *something that might possibly happen in the future, usually causing problems or making further arrangements necessary*. You could go for ***external** contingency*, but I don't see the point in trying to get that precise about something which is *by definition* not clearly definable!

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: The problem isn't the charge, the problem is that some or all customers are upset that the charge is being levied because you find yourselves no longer able to absorb the cost of providing the service. What you have is a **customer relations problem** because levying the charge might mean that some customers move to a competitor. Your problem lies in presenting the charge in such a way that the number of customers transferring to competitors is minimised. You don't have an **interdepartmental problem** because the departmental managers accept the charge.

Answer (score 1):

In view of:

> But, (predictably) the customers do not want to pay, as they got used to getting the services for free.

From [the Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/consumer-resistance)

> **consumer resistance** noun [ U ]
>
> **MARKETING**
>
> the fact of people disliking or being unwilling to buy a particular product or service:
>
> meet with/overcome consumer resistance
>
> The prospect of bioengineered food crops has met strong consumer resistance in Europe.

Answer (score -1):

Egress [source](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/egress):

> 1. a place or means of going out
> 2. the action or right of going or coming out

I'd name it "egress exemption".